# Behavior of function with anonymous function in it

Tags: anonymous-function, sml, smlnj

Being new to SML, using SML NJ I recognized this behavior of a function:

```
- fun test g= fn x=>x;
val test : 'a -> 'b -> 'b = _fn
- test 1 2;
val it : int = 2
- test 1;
val it : '1 -> '1 = _fn
```

Is it so, that the interpreter uses `unit` as datatype for the input parameter g, if no value is given for it at the call of the function? If so, why is this happening to g and not the input parameter for the anonymous function?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  "Is it so, that the interpreter uses unit as datatype for the input parameter g."  This isn't true, it uses type `'a`.  Also, you are violating the [value restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction) when doing `test 1`.

Comment: This question is very unclear. The result of `test 1` is a function. You can apply it: `it 2;` would result in `val it : int = 2`.

Comment: Oh okay thanks @molbdnilo . As I'm very new to SML I didn't see that. This just explains my question.

Comment: @Matt Oh okay, didn't hear anything of a value restriction before. So I'm violating the value restriction, because test 1 is not a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @molbdnilo `test 1;` would only bind the value of the function test (`fn x=>x`) to `it`. So 1 is assigned to `g` at the first call. A call of `it` with some paramter will execute the `fn x=>x` part.